# How do I add a non-Steam game from an SD Card in SteamOS?

Tags: linux, sd-card, steam, steam-os

I have an .exe file saved to my Micro SD card that I want to play in in SteamOS. Normally in desktop mode I can access my SD Card under "removable devices", but when I use Steam's "Add a non Steam-Game" option there's no option to select my SD Card.

How do I select a file on my SD Card when adding a non-steam game in SteamOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your external storage should be under `/run/media/mmcblk0p1`.

1. Insert your Micro SD card (formatted as ext4)
2. Go to SteamOS's Desktop mode
3. Open Steam and click Add a Game > Add a Non-Steam Game...
4. Click Browse
5. Under File type select "All Files"
6. Under "Look In" select `/`
7. Navigate to `/run/media/mmcblk0p1`
8. Select the game you want to add and click OK.
9. Back in steam, right click the newly added game and hit Properties
10. Go to Compatibility and check "Force the use of a specific Steam Play compatibility tool"